# Trouble loading a JSON file located on my computer

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using AngularJS' `http()` method to load in a JSON file located on my computer. The contents of the file are:

```
{
  "topics": [
    {
      "canonical": "Nebraska Football",
      "alias": "NEB",
      "score": 45,
    },
    {
      "canonical": "Ohio State Football",
      "alias": "OSU",
      "score": 10,
    }
  ]
}
```

When I load the file (named example.json), I get an error message while using both Firefox and Safari that says `Error: JSON.parse: expected double-quoted property name`. In Chrome (as expected thanks to its default security) it just plain doesn't work.

The JSON was originally loading fine in Firefox, but after a browser update it stopped working.

I am calling the JSON like this:

```
$http.get("json/example.json").success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I tried using Python's SimpleHTTPServer to run the site as well, and it didn't make a difference. If anyone has any guesses as to what is going wrong here, I would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: You can launch Chrome fresh (meaning without it already open, or any chrome.exe processes running) with the command line `--allow-file-access-from-files` and it'll allow local file loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invalid Json 
try

```
{
    "topics": [
    {
        "canonical": "Nebraska Football",
        "alias": "NEB",
        "score": 45
    },
    {
        "canonical": "Ohio State Football",
        "alias": "OSU",
        "score": 10
    }
]
}
```

Comment: I am hating myself for chasing that error this last hour. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you run your JSON through jsonlint.com it points the error to `},{`. If you look up from there you will see trailing `,`'s that shouldn't be there. Your JSON should probably be:

```
{
  "topics": [
    {
      "canonical": "Nebraska Football",
      "alias": "NEB",
      "score": 45
    },
    {
      "canonical": "Ohio State Football",
      "alias": "OSU",
      "score": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified code: removing ',' from last item may solve your problem

```
{
  "topics": [
    {
      "canonical": "Nebraska Football",
      "alias": "NEB",
      "score": 45
    },
    {
      "canonical": "Ohio State Football",
      "alias": "OSU",
      "score": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have extra `,`s in your JSON. Modify it as follows:

```
{
  "topics": [
    {
      "canonical": "Nebraska Football",
      "alias": "NEB",
      "score": 45
    },
    {
      "canonical": "Ohio State Football",
      "alias": "OSU",
      "score": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) is a good place to validate your JSON. It's saying that you should remove the commas `,` after the final value in each array element. So `"score":45,` should be `"score":45`